# Is there a way to implement the Cleaner with primitives other than boxing them in classes?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-inline-class

So, we have a kotlin wrapper around [vulkan](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/vkk) which relies on inline classes for vulkan identifiers (which are usually `Long`s)

As far as I got, Java (9+) `Cleaner` is supposed to work only with classes.

[Here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/gc/ref-cleaner.html) an example

I tried to modify that in order to run with plain primitives

```
fun main() {
    val cleaner = Cleaner.create()
    for (i in 0..9) {
        val id = Integer.toString(i)
        val vkObject = 0L + i
        cleaner.register(vkObject, CleanerRunnable(id))
    }

    //myObjects are not reachable anymore
    //do some other memory intensive work
    for (i in 1..10000) {
        val a = IntArray(10000)
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1)
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        }

    }
}
```

But unfortunately without success.

So my question is if there is a way to have `Cleaner` working with primitives representing native off-heap resources without having to wrap them in classes

Comment: Maybe using the object type e.g. Long and rely on auto boxing?

Comment: What do you mean by rely on auto boxing?

Comment: `Cleaner` and off-heap are mutually exclusive. `Cleaner` and primitives are mutually exclusive. What is your actual goal?

Comment: To replicate the `Unique` handle of [vulkan hpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp#uniquehandle-for-automatic-resource-management) for automatic resource management